# Sending text line-by-line to a discord webhook

Tags: discord.py, webhooks

I'm trying to send text from a wordlist line-by-line into a discord channel via a discord webhook. The script below only sends the last line in the wordlist for some reason.

```css
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

with open('wordlist.txt','r') as lines:    
    for line in lines:
                webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='webhookurlhere', content=lines.readline()

response = webhook.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

file = open("wordlist.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    webhook= DiscordWebhook(url='myurl', content= line)

response = webhook.exectute()
file.close()
```

it appears you were missing a closing parenthesis on your discordwebhook call. i also structured the reading of the file a little differently, just easier for reading for me. see if this works for you.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to work. It only sends the last line of the wordlist. It must be an issue with line splicing as the script works when it output it to a print command.